# copy all webalizer.hist files via ssh

Tags: ssh, whm

I have file webalizer.hist in every user acount /home/*/tmp/webalizerftp/webalizer.hist
* - is username.

I need to copy them all to another dir '/home/stats/' and rename them in this style
/home/some_username/tmp/webalizerftp/webalizer.hist -> /home/stats/some_username.hist
/home/another_username/tmp/webalizerftp/webalizer.hist -> /home/stats/another_username.hist

I need to do it via SSH.

Can you help me please?